# Bash script which starts on startup to do 3 things

Tags: server, bash, scripts, init.d, pptpd

I have add the following to my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
folder=/home/secrets
inotifywait -m -q -e create -r --format '%:e %w%f' $folder | while read file
  do
     mv -f /home/secrets/chaps.secrets /etc/ppp/chap-secrets 
     sudo service pptpd restart
  done
exit 0
```

What this does is watch a folder that I SCP to with a new secrets file, when it is added it moves it to the live secrets file, this works great for users that are added to the secrets file, however this doesn't kick off any existing users that are no longer in the secrets file.  I have tried to add

```
sudo killall -wq pppd
```

to the script before the pptpd service restart, but that seems to fail.

What can I do to watch the folder, copy the file, kill all ppp connections and then restart the pptpd service? The routers reconnect when the service is restarted so they see no drop in service.

Comment: in case you are wondering, it's in the /etc/rc.local so that it starts on boot and reboots.

Comment: If your script is in `/etc/rc.local`, it's already run as `root`, no `sudo` needed.